# When i was allocate new memory in heap in J meter ,Memory Leak was happen

Tags: java, jmeter

My question is how should i release memory from the heap?

"My c drive had more than 40 GB space but now it showing less than 3 GB"
C:\Windows\system32>java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | findstr /i "HeapSize PermSize ThreadStackSize"

```
 intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0
      {pd product}

uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0
      {product}

uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520
      {product}

uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 62914560
      {product}

uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728
      {product}

uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 987758592
      {product}

 intx ThreadStackSize                           = 0
      {pd product}

 intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 0
      {pd product}
```

java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

C:\Windows\system32>
java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'

when after allocating memory in heap i was run program using jmeter each and every time its allocate space in c drive..**@Peter Lawrey**

Comment: You might want to find out what the heap is.

Comment: No, i want to release memory from the heap. just tell me how to do that?

Comment: Heap memory does not consume space on your hard drive, except if memory is so overloaded your page file is growing, and that's unlikely. If you want to see what's using up your C: drive, use a tool like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/).

Comment: actually i got this problem 1st time ,i couldn't find the solution, i am using j-mete got exception out of memory error then i allocate new memory in heap after that i got error heap created dump file and my c drive was full continuously..just tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

When your disk space fills up you need to find the files you don't need and clean them up.

If you have produced a heap dump I suggest you look for a large file in the directory where your program ran.

BTW When a program exits, all the resource it used are freed up except any files it leaves behind.

Comment: i searched my directory in which place my program are running but i got there are approx 150 MB file are generated ?Can you suggest me any tool for this that for i can find the solution and i am trying to use VisualVM 1.3.8 version

Comment: @PInkF disk space is managed by your operating system. On Linux you would use du to find where your dis space is being used.  I am not sure what is the best tool is for Windows, but the tool you are looking for for your disk usage is not a Java program it is a utility tool for your operating system.

Comment: @PinkF, since you are using windows, just use this simple tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/windirstat/ .

Answer (score 0):

Use TreeSize Free tools and open it with Administrator and search java_.hprof files fie from there and go to directory and delete those file from there!!!